# FIlter instances that has the same field as instance id of which I provide in one query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have simple model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    group_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Let say i have only available `user_id`, and I need to retrieve all the users that has the same `group_uuid` as user id of which I have in `user_id` variable.

Not sure if we can utilize `F` or `Subquery` object in some ways.

So we want to achieve this in one query:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
User.objects.filter(group_uuid=Subquery(user))
```

This obviously is NOT making one query, but it should be possible to make it in one right?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply work with the `.group_id` of the `user`:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
User.objects.filter(group_uuid=user.group_uuid)
```

Or if you need one query, you can work with `.filter(…)` instead of `.get(…)` for the `user`:

```
user_uuids = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).values('group_uuid')
User.objects.filter(group_uuid__in=user_uuids)
```

Since `QuerySet`s are lazy, it will not perform the `user_uuids` query, but simply encode this as a subquery.

That being said, using subqueries are not always more efficient. Especially MySQL is known to recalculate the subquery *per element*, even if the subquery is "constant" with respect to that item.

Comment: That why we use postgress whenever possible. Thanks! This looks good!